# Drive permissions in AndroidManifest.xml via Titanium's tiapp.xml

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I am attempting to upload a mobile app I developed using **titanium-mobile** to the Google Play marketplace.  I am getting the following message:

> **This apk requests 4 permissions that users will be warned about**
>   android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
>   android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
>   android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
>   android.permission.INTERNET
>
> **This apk requests 2 features that will be used for Google Play filtering**
>   android.hardware.touchscreen
>   android.hardware.wifi

When developing apps natively, I was able to modify these permissions directly via the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.  With Titanium I do not actually generate the `AndroidManifest.xml` myself but rather it is generated by Titanium's build.

Is there a way to send directives to titanium's build engine via **`tiapp.xml`** to  remove, enable, or disable permissions in the titanium generated `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot edit permissions via `tiapp.xml`.

You can edit the `AndroidManifest.xml` file directly 

(located at `{TitaniumWorkspace}/{ProjectRoot}/build/android/AndroidManifest.xml`) 
then copy and edit this file.  After that ensure that you put it in your root project directory with the following folder hierarchy:

1. Your root project folder
2. `platform` (note: you may have to create this folder)
3. `android` (note: you may have to create this folder)
4. `AndroidManifest.xml`

Example path for where to put the edited manifest:  `{TitaniumWorkspace}/{ProjectRoot}/platform/android/AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Hrm, I had read about this solution via http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/129962/disable-android-permissions but was hoping there was a way to do this directly via tiapp.xml.  Too bad!  Thanks though :)